# How to change color to tab divisor in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

How can I change color of this tab/window divider in PyCharm/WebStorm?

[image: Divisor in light theme]

Because when I change the theme to Dracula I lose it:

[image: Divisor in Dracula theme]